# Typewriter sequence on R

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, sequence-of-function

I'm familiar with the typewriter sequence on the unit interval, but I'm wondering if there is a way to extend it to the entire real line. If there is, could someone explain how to make such an extension or provide a formula for such a sequence?

Answer (score 1):

You can divide $[-N,N]$ into intervals of length $1/N$ (or $2^{-N}$), and increase $N$ to infinity.

Comment: How explicitly could I write that? When I tried to do that I kept staying within [0,1] as n got larger

Comment: @math99 When you do as suggested, you will have $2N^2$ subintervals.